# How Safe is an Obscure File Download Link?

Tags: apache, download, vcf-vcard, directory-listing, security-by-obscurity

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I want to distribute my Vcard (.vcf) file by hosting it on my personal website (this part is a rigid requirement).  People will access it from a QR code on my business card, however, **no links to the file will exist on my webpages**.

I want to make the file publicly accessible, while ensuring that it doesn't get scraped by a bot.  It will be contained in a folder disallowed from "normal" bots via robots.txt, and I will disable directory listings in Apache.

I do NOT want to introduce additional steps such as captchas or authentication.

My thought is something like how google drive does public sharing - a 44-character random string that represents the file.  So....

http://mywebsite.com/private/34599771831821330576336168849178778047996955.vcf

My questions are:

1) How safe is this?  Presumably, as long as I disable directory listing on Apache, the only way a bot can stumble on the file without a direct link is via random guessing.  Do bots really bother trying to do just a thing?

2) If it's safe, presumably string length is key.  Just how long does the string need to be to make it "safe"?

3) Is there a better way to do this than filename obscurity?

Comment: I've seen so many obscure URLs getting picked up by Google over the years (with no idea how they did it), I don't trust this method any more. Even a simple password is better than just a URL if it's really sensitive data.

Comment: It's not terribly sensitive, so I'd rather err on the side of open(on the assumption that many people already struggle with QR Codes + vcards and will give up if I add another step of authentication.  The containing folder will certainly be disallowed from "legal" bots...I'm just worried about "illegal" ones.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way. It is called recaptcha.
The idea should be to present the user with the captcha and if he/she/it solves it correctly, then you proceed to the download.

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html

Comment: I updated my post as I should have stated that more clearly - I do not want to introduce additional steps (burden) on the end user.  QR codes are already a pain for people, and I'm afraid they'll give up if they have to jump through hoops.